# Achievement's timestamp header is not updated after refreshing on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

I think I stumbled over a minor bug in the Android app.

Synopsis:

1. Participate in an SE site and gain positive reputation. Just to clarify, this does not need to be done via the app. In my case, e.g., this reproduced  by answering questions in SO from my laptop.
2. Open the Android app and hit the *Achievement* button. The rep gain should be displayed correctly under the "Today" heading.
3. Do not close the achievement dialog and do not gain reputation the following day (passing 0:00 UTC).
4. Return to the app - the reputation is still displayed under "Today", as it was left. Pulling down in order to refresh displays the refreshing icon, but the heading is left as "Today". Closing the achievements dialog and reopening it will correctly display the reputation gain under a "Yesterday" heading.

Version info:

- SE Android app version <strike>1.0.56</strike> also reproduced with 1.0.57 too.
- Android 5.0.1
- Nexus 4

**EDIT (27/07/2016):**
Rechecked with version 1.0.85 on the same device, and it seems to be working now. Can one of the moderators please add a proper status tag to this post?

Comment: Still repro'd on v1.0.83. Reloading the achievement while passing the day (**0:00 UTC**) didn't update the timestamp, and needs hard-reload by closing and reopening the achievement. It actually makes me wonder if reloading achievement from there is actually working or not.